# How to intergrate IQEngine API in upload page in Node JS

Tags: node.js

Here is [IQengine API](https://github.com/iqengines/nodejs-iqengines/blob/master/tests.js)
So I upload an image through upload page in node js and api send the image to the engine and get a result then the result is displayed in the page.
Can you write the simple code?
Thank you.